# Mocking third party service

Tags: junit, mocking

How to mock a third party service without actually calling it? I have written unit test case for the rest controller for post method. But instead of mocking the service, it is actually calling the service. Any solutions?

Comment: You already have 3 answers below. Did that solve your problem? If not I advise you to add yout Test here and then let us help !

Comment: Here is my test case

Comment: I am not able to add test case here.

Comment: By here I mean in your original post/question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways that you can mock a call to the third party service.

1. Using dependency injection to have a test version of the call to the third party service.

Guice, Spring etc. will allow you to inject dependencies that will mimic the behavior of your third-party service.

2. Using Mockito / Powermock etc. frameworks

Assuming you have an Object that controls the access to the third-party service, you can use Mockito and other frameworks to intercept the calls to the Object and return specific results without contacting the third party service.

Here is an example talking to a database https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mockito/mockito-mock-database-connection-example/

Answer (score 0):

You have a few alternatives:

(1) Use [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to separate your application logic from the calls to the third party API. In your unit tests, you should mock the adapter. See [this article](https://8thlight.com/blog/eric-smith/2011/10/27/thats-not-yours.html) for more details on this pattern. The disadvantage is that the adapter itself remains hard to test.

(2) Some APIs like [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/development) provide a test mode that you can use for testing.

(3) Use [unmock](https://unmock.io). The library captures API calls and serves back reliable mock data. You can also use it for testing server errors ("flaky mode") and performing stochastic testing.

Note that I'm one of the unmock developers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Mockito:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnSituation() throws IOException {

    ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>(BIGDATA_RESPONSE, HttpStatus.OK);

    mockRestTemplateResponse(response);

    Object actualSituation = resolver.resolve(baseDto);

    assertEquals("REGULAR", actualSituation);

    verify(restTemplate).exchange(requestEntityCaptor.capture(), eq(String.class));

    assertEquals("http://example.com/any/01234567890", requestEntityCaptor.getValue().getUrl().toString());
}
```

And below is another example:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnFalseWhenNotFound() throws IOException {

    HttpClientErrorException exception = new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    doThrow(exception).when(restTemplate).exchange(any(RequestEntity.class), eq(String.class));

    Object result = resolver.resolve(baseDto);

    assertFalse((Boolean) result);
}
```